# Distance span between two binary strings

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is there any way of finding efficiently (bitwise operations) the distance (**not** Hamming Distance!) of two 8-bit binary strings?

Each byte is guaranteed to have only one bit set.

Like:

```
a=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
b=0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 -> distance = 3
          ^^^^^ 
------
a=0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
b=0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 -> distance = 3
      ^^^^^
------
a=0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
b=0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 -> distance = 4
      ^^^^^^^
```

I could work with something like logarithms but that is not very efficient

Comment: Minor point: if you want dist(a, a) = 0 (typical for a distance function), then it would make sense to increment your distances by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Efficient" can mean a different things here: e.g., asymptotic vs performance for a known range of inputs; time vs space; etc.

I'll assume you care about raw speed for the small bounded inputs you describe.

**Baseline approach.** Take the smaller bit, and left shift it until it's equal to the larger bit, counting shifts. While this is O(n), that sort of analysis doesn't matter here since n is bounded.

You might compare that baseline to either of the following approaches, which have better time complexity but may or may not be faster for your inputs.

**Alternative 1.** Put all the distances in a lookup matrix. O(1) time complexity, but O(n^2) space complexity.

**Alternative 2.** Have a lookup table for the logarithms, and return the difference log<sub>2</sub>(a) - log<sub>2</sub>(b), where a >= b. O(1) time complexity, O(n) space complexity. (Note that I'm assuming that dist(a, a) = 0, which is a off-by-one from what you describe above.)

I don't know in practice which of those will be faster, but the main point is not to assume that O(n) means that the algorithm is slower in absolute terms for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operation (logical summing) and then find a maximum amount of zeros, which goes one by one. Hope i get your question right.

Comment: @WillieWheeler oh, yep, my mistake, i was thinking about OR operator, sorry